# Identifying Visible Lists through SharePoint Web Services

Tags: jquery, xml, web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-list

all! I'm having some issues using SharePoint Web Services to identify the lists available in my server. I'm using GetListCollection to get all the lists and associated properties from my server, and filtering for "BaseType=0" to identify the custom lists. However, the results include "hidden" custom lists such as the "Content type publishing error log" list, among others.

I've tried comparing the XML for two specific lists excerpted from GetListCollection's output, one of which is hidden and one of which is visible, and can't find any differences.

Does anyone know if there is a single property or combination of properties that defines a list as hidden in GetListCollection's output? (By hidden, I mean users cannot see the list in the list of Lists, and it is not on the left-hand menu in SharePoint, if that makes sense.)

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Resolved. I'm blind as a bat. There's a Hidden="True/False" attribute in the list tag in the XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. I'm blind as a bat. There's a Hidden="True/False" attribute in the list tag in the XML.